# How do I prevent CheckChanged to fire after setting Checked in that event?

Tags: c#, events

I have this code in my CheckedChanged event handler:

```
private void cbLoadStock_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (cbLoadStock.Checked == false &&
            MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to do that?",
            "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) == DialogResult.Yes) {

            cbLoadStock.Checked = true;
        } else {
            cbLoadStock.Checked = false;
        }
    }
```

But, when I click "Yes", it sets `Checked` to `true` causing the handler to be called again.

How can I make the checkbox to just be set checked?

Comment: remove event handler at run time and add it again.

Comment: @Afshin I got that, but it is that really the Correct Way to do this?

Comment: I'm not expert in c#, but I think it is correct way. have seen similar approach in android too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, this should do the work:

```
private void cbLoadStock_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        cbLoadStock.CheckedChanged -= cbLoadStock_CheckedChanged;
        if (cbLoadStock.Checked == false &&
            MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to do that?",
            "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) == DialogResult.Yes) {

            cbLoadStock.Checked = true;
        } else {
            cbLoadStock.Checked = false;
        }
        cbLoadStock.CheckedChanged += cbLoadStock_CheckedChanged;
    }
```